# Problem with centering text in Column flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment, whitespace, centering

so i want to move this "pow" text there where the X is. White arrow is just an example what is happening if i instead of
**alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter** typing **alignment: Alignment.bottomRight**, can someone tell me why this text has some magic area and i can't get him down there

[image: example]

```
 body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox.fromSize(
              size: const Size(300, 300),
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Start",
                      style: GoogleFonts.overpass(
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  child: Text("pow",
                      style: GoogleFonts.oxygen(
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the `Align` is only aligning its child within the `Column`, not the entire screen.

You can fix it like this:

```
body: Stack(
  children: [
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
        size: const Size(300, 300),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Material(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Start",
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Text(
          "pow",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

It works because the `Stack` takes up the whole screen

Answer (score 0):

```
body:Container(
height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.80,
 child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox.fromSize(
              size: const Size(300, 300),
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Start",
                      style: GoogleFonts.overpass(
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  child: Text("pow",
                      style: GoogleFonts.oxygen(
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))),
            ),
          ],
        ),
)
```